# Read SSIS package XML & convert it to tabular format

Tags: c#, xml, ssis

I am trying to read ssis package in c# I have used below code but I am getting error while executing it

```
string filepath = "C:\\Package.dtsx";
          System.IO.StreamReader myFile =
           new System.IO.StreamReader(filepath);
        string myString = myFile.ReadToEnd();

        myFile.Close();

        StringReader theReader = new StringReader(myString);
        DataSet theDataSet = new DataSet();
        theDataSet.ReadXml(theReader);

        DataTable dt = theDataSet.Tables[0];
```

> The table (ConnectionManager) cannot be the child table to itself in nested relations.

is there any way I can read ssis package and convert it into a tabular format?

Comment: In your mind, how would a package appear in tabular format? What would that look like?

Comment: @billinkc When i open my package in notepad and copy paste everything in that package here http://xmlgrid.net/ . I got one decent tabular format

Comment: It appears the functionality of theDataSet.Tables[0] does not match the functionality of xmlgrid.net

Comment: I actually receive this run time error at **theDataSet.ReadXml(theReader);**